# How to read multiple types of json from one topic in kafka springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have one topic from which I can receive different types of jsons. However, it appears that I'm getting an exception while the consumer tries to read the message. I tried to add additional bean names but that didn't work. It seems that its trying reading from the topic and trying to convert to all the types that are reading from the topic. Is there a way to specify that only a particular factory should be enabled for a particular input type. Is there any other way to fix the issue.

ERROR

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException:
>   Cannot convert from
>   [com.lte.assessment.assessments.AssessmentAttemptRequest] to
>   [com.lte.assessmentanalytics.data.SiteLevelAnalyticsRequest] for
>   GenericMessage
>   [payload=com.lte.assessment.assessments.AssessmentAttemptRequest@68eb637f,
>   headers={kafka_offset=22,
>   kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@252d8ffb,
>   kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null,
>   kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=ltetopic,
>   kafka_receivedTimestamp=1546117529267}

Config

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
    static Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap();

    static {
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, AssessmentAttemptRequest> assessmentAttemptDetailsEntityConsumerFactory() {
        JsonDeserializer<AssessmentAttemptRequest> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        deserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.lte.assessment.assessments");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(config, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
    }

    @Bean(name="aaKafkaListenerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory aaKafkaListenerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AssessmentAttemptRequest> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(assessmentAttemptDetailsEntityConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, AssessmentQuestionAnalyticsEntity> assessmentQuestionAnalyticssEntityConsumerFactory() {
        JsonDeserializer<AssessmentQuestionAnalyticsEntity> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        deserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.lte.assessment.assessments");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(config, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
    }

    @Bean(name="aqKafkaListenerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory aqKafkaListenerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AssessmentQuestionAnalyticsEntity> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(assessmentQuestionAnalyticssEntityConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SiteLevelAnalyticsEntity> siteLevelAnalyticsEntityConsumerFactory() {
        JsonDeserializer<SiteLevelAnalyticsEntity> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        deserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.lte.assessment.assessments");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(config, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
    }

    @Bean("slaKafkaListenerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory slaKafkaListenerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SiteLevelAnalyticsEntity> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(siteLevelAnalyticsEntityConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class TopicObserver implements
        ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback,ConsumerSeekAware{

    @Autowired
    private AssessmentAttemptService assessmentAttemptService;

    @Autowired
    private AssessmentQuestionService assessmentQuestionService;

    @Autowired
    private SiteLevelAnalyticsService siteLevelAnalyticsService;

    private final ThreadLocal<ConsumerSeekCallback> seekCallBack = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "ltetopic", groupId = "group_id", containerFactory = "aaKafkaListenerFactory")
    public void consumeAttemptDetails(AssessmentAttemptRequest request) {
        assessmentAttemptService.storeAttempDetails(request);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "ltetopic", groupId = "group_id", containerFactory = "aqKafkaListenerFactory")
    public void setAssessmentQeustionAnalytics(AssessmentQuestionRequest request) {
        assessmentQuestionService.storeQuestionDetails(request);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "ltetopic", groupId = "group_id", containerFactory = "slaKafkaListenerFactory")
    public void siteLevelAnalytics(SiteLevelAnalyticsRequest request) {
        siteLevelAnalyticsService.storeSiteLevelDetailsDetails(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not right approach to do that, every `KafkaListener` will try to consume all the messages from topic, and only matched one will be deserialized and remaining will thrown an exception, i will suggest to use ` @KafkaHandler` and follow this article  https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#kafka-listener-annotation

Answer (score 1):

@Deadpool is right. If you need a simpler solution, consume your messages as a String JSON payload and manually deserialize them to your objects.

```
        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> createConsumerFactory() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
              kafkaEmbedded().getBrokersAsString());
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
        }

        @Bean
        public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(createConsumerFactory());
            return factory;
        }
```

In your Listener, consume as String.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = YOUR_TOPIC)
    public void listen(String json){
    //Convert to Object here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, SiteLevelAnalyticsEntity> siteLevelAnalyticsEntityConsumerFactory() {
    JsonDeserializer<SiteLevelAnalyticsEntity> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
    deserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.lte.assessment.assessments");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(config, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
}
```

in consumer factory you assign `SiteLevelAnalyticsEntity` and  `JsonDeserializer` is assessments package .
pls define --`deserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.lte.assessment.SiteLevelAnalyticsEntity");`