# Can We Work with Multiple Json Format from Single Topic using Single Stream App in Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 2 json format in same kafka topic

1. 1st JSON

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "name",
  "values": [
     "one": 1,
     "two": 2,
     "three": 3,
     "four": 4
   ]
}
```

2. 2nd JSON

```
{
  "id": 8,
  "title": "Microsoft Surface Laptop 4",
  "description": "Style and speed. Stand out on ...",
  "price": 1499,
  "discountPercentage": 10.23,
  "rating": 4.43,
  "stock": 68,
  "brand": "Microsoft Surface",
  "category": "laptops",
  "thumbnail": "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/8/thumbnail.jpg",
  "images": [
    "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/8/1.jpg",
    "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/8/2.jpg",
    "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/8/3.jpg",
    "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/8/4.jpg",
    "https://dummyjson.com/image/i/products/8/thumbnail.jpg"
  ]
}
```

I want to perform some transformation on these two JSON's with single Stream application and produce output in different topics.
Is it possible to work with single stream app ? if yes, then how?
Iam currently using JAVA for stream application

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53973375/how-to-read-multiple-types-of-json-from-one-topic-in-kafka-springboot   Basically send them and deal with them as Strings, then in the backend transform them as you will.

Comment: @JCompetence That's for plain consumer, not Streams

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can consume the data as generic JsonObject/JsonNode classes using builtin JSON deserializer, then check for specific fields in a filter/branch operator before parsing to a specific POJO.

Or you can use String Serde, pass strings to JSON parsers, and do the same.

Alternatively, use two different topics and join events based on the ID field, for example